# Possible to use either an AccessToken or Identity token as a credential to Connect-AzureAD / MSGraph?

Tags: asp.net-identity, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, azure-powershell, powershell-remoting

I have a multi-tenant AzureAD app that calls a number of PowerShell scripts under the context of the logged in user of my webapp.

Is it possible to pass either the AccessToken or IDToken to the PowerShell script and have it create a session with `Connect-AzureAD` commandlet?

I see a credentials overload, and perhaps there might be a way to use (or convert) a token into something usable with this parameter?

```
PS C:\Users> get-help connect-azuread -examples

NAME
Connect-AzureAD

SYNOPSIS
Connects with an authenticated account to use Active Directory cmdlet requests.


Example 1: Connect a PowerShell session to a tenant

PS C:\> Connect-AzureAD -Confirm

This command connects the current PowerShell session to an Azure Active Directory tenant. The command prompts you
for a username and password for the tenant you want to connect to. The Confirm parameter prompts you for
confirmation.

If multi-factor authentication is enabled for your credentials, you must log in using the interactive option or
use service principal authentication.
Example 2: Connect a session using a variable

PS C:\> $Credential = Get-Credential
PS C:\> Connect-AzureAD -Credential $Credential

The first command gets the user credentials, and then stores them in the $Credential variable.

The second command connects the current PowerShell session using the credentials in $Credential.

This account authenticates with Azure Active Directory using organizational ID credentials. You cannot use
multi-factor authentication or Microsoft account credentials to run Azure Active Directory cmdlets with this
account.
Example 3: Connect a session as a service principal

# Login to Azure AD PowerShell With Admin Account
Connect-AzureAD

# Create the self signed cert
$currentDate = Get-Date
$endDate = $currentDate.AddYears(1)
$notAfter = $endDate.AddYears(1)
$pwd = "<password>"
$thumb = (New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation cert:\localmachine\my -DnsName com.foo.bar -KeyExportPolicy
Exportable -Provider "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider" -NotAfter $notAfter).Thumbprint
$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $pwd -Force -AsPlainText
Export-PfxCertificate -cert "cert:\localmachine\my\$thumb" -FilePath c:\temp\examplecert.pfx -Password $pwd

# Load the certificate
$cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate("C:\temp\examplecert.pfx", $pwd)
$keyValue = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($cert.GetRawCertData())


# Create the Azure Active Directory Application
$application = New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName "test123" -IdentifierUris "https://test123"
New-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential -ObjectId $application.ObjectId -CustomKeyIdentifier "Test123" -StartDate
$currentDate -EndDate $endDate -Type AsymmetricX509Cert -Usage Verify -Value $keyValue

# Create the Service Principal and connect it to the Application
$sp=New-AzureADServicePrincipal -AppId $application.AppId

# Give the Service Principal Reader access to the current tenant (Get-AzureADDirectoryRole)
Add-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember -ObjectId 5997d714-c3b5-4d5b-9973-ec2f38fd49d5 -RefObjectId $sp.ObjectId

# Get Tenant Detail
$tenant=Get-AzureADTenantDetail
# Now you can login to Azure PowerShell with your Service Principal and Certificate
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $tenant.ObjectId -ApplicationId  $sp.AppId -CertificateThumbprint $thumb

This command authenticates the user to Azure Active Directory as a service principal.
```

Comment: If you check the parameters, you can do e.g. `Connect-AzureAD -MsAccessToken $token` so I'd imagine it'll work. You cannot use an Id token though. You need an access token, either for MS Graph API or AAD Graph API, depending which API the particular cmdlet that you want to use is using.

Comment: @juunas Thank you. My brain is getting twisted as I try to figure out the authentication flow from a Blazor Webassembly (is it like Xamarin or Javascript) ...then how do I use that to call an AD API ... that calls powershell backend ... that calls GraphAPI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example：

```
Connect-AzureAD
       -TenantId {Tenant ID}
       -AadAccessToken {AAD Graph Access Token}
       -MsAccessToken {Microsoft Graph Access Token}
       -AccountId {Your UPN}
```

Please note that if you must provide `AadAccessToke` because you are connecting to AAD module.

`MsAccessToken` is optional. But if you need to use some cmds which require Microsoft Graph permission, you should provide `MsAccessToken`. An example is `Get-AzureADPolicy`.

Only access token can be used here. Id token is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

The last parameter set in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/connect-azuread?view=azureadps-2.0) outlines `AADAccessToken` parameter.

```
Connect-AzureAD
       [-AzureEnvironmentName <EnvironmentName>]
       [-TenantId <String>]
       -AadAccessToken <String>
       [-MsAccessToken <String>]
       -AccountId <String>
       [-LogLevel <LogLevel>]
       [-LogFilePath <String>]
       [-InformationAction <ActionPreference>]
       [-InformationVariable <String>]
       [-WhatIf]
       [-Confirm]
       [<CommonParameters>]
```

You can use an `access token` in the Connect-AzureAD powershell cmdlet to connect to Azure AD. But it must be an **access** not **id** token. And its audience must be the Microsoft Graph.